# How to bulk insert with Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have something like the following loop, which creates many inserts:

```
table = Arel::Table.new(:users)
users.each do |user|
  manager = Arel::InsertManager.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
  manager.into(table).insert([
    [table[:name], user.name],
    [table[:created_at], user.created_at],
    [table[:updated_at], user.updated_at]
  ])
  # INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('a')
  @conn.insert(manager.to_sql)
end
```

However, I would like to find a way to get only the values to be inserted. In this was I would be able to do a single insert for all values.

PS: please note I don't wan't to write sql strings (security concerns).

```
table = Arel::Table.new(:users)
inserts = []
users.each do |user|
  manager = Arel::InsertManager.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
  manager.into(table).insert([
    [table[:name], user.name],
    [table[:created_at], user.created_at],
    [table[:updated_at], user.updated_at]
  ])
  inserts << "(#{??manage values??})"
end
# INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')
@conn.insert(????)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking the [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) (thanks to @Gavin Miller), I realised they use Rails [cote](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote) that prevents sql injections.

Because I need something customised I'm not going for the gem. So, my final solution is below in case someone else has a similar requirement:

```
inserts = []
users.each do |user|
  inserts << %{(
    #{@conn.quote(user.name)},
    #{@conn.quote(user.created_at)},
    #{@conn.quote(user.updated_at)}
  )}
end

sql = %{
  INSERT INTO users
  (name, created_at, updated_at)
  VALUES #{inserts.join(',')}
}

@conn.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 4):

There was a library that came out earlier this month called [`bulk_insert`](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert). This should provide you with the functionality you're looking for:

```
Model.bulk_insert do |worker|
  worker.add(...)
  worker.add(...)
  ...
end

# Produces:
INSERT INTO models (...) VALUES
  (...),
  (...),
  (...),
  (...),
  ...
```

As it's a fairly new library, and I haven't had a chance to play with it, I'm uncertain on it's Arel capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

If your AREL version support `create_tuple` already it will be like:

```
        table = Table.new(:users)
        manager = Arel::InsertManager.new
        manager.into table

        manager.columns << table[:id]
        manager.columns << table[:name]

        manager.values = manager.create_tuple([
          manager.create_values(%w{ 1 david }),
          manager.create_values(%w{ 2 kirs }),
          manager.create_values(["3", Arel.sql('DEFAULT')], []),
        ])

        # INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "name") VALUES ('1', 'david'), ('2', 'kirs'), ('3', DEFAULT)
      end
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/kirs/arel/blob/5d6d14cb6be217abc04253da0fe49721d09e9575/test/test_insert_manager.rb#L31

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Active Record Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import).